# Is this a free variable? Something else?

Tags: logic, definition, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am struggling to understand the terminology behind free variables.

If we have $\forall x \ P(x)$ I would believe $x$ is bound and not free.

If we have $\forall x \ P(x, y)$ I believe $y$ is free, as it is not "bound" / "quantified over" / "attached to a quantifier".

Is this right so far?

Now, if we're using $\forall$ elim and we turn $\forall x \ P(x)$ into $P(a)$ on the next line, what is $a$ here? Does this "become" a free variable? A constant? A term? Something else? What is this?

Comment: $\forall x P(x)$ : YES, $x$ not free (i.e. bound). $\forall x P(x,y)$ : YES, $x$ not free, $y$ free.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'd be careful saying "a constant is always free" since "constant" may be confused with "constant *symbol*," and of course constant symbols (not being variables) are neither free nor bound.

Comment: In $P(a)$, the term $a$ is free, if $a$ is listed in the syntactical specifications of the language as a *variable*. If instead $a$ is listed as a *constant* symbol of the language, well... it is a constant. The distinction free/bound applies **only** to *variables*. You have to check on your textbook: maybe $a,b,c$ are listed at the beginning of FOL treatment (dealing with *syntax*) as (individual) *constants*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guesses are right. Re: your question, you have *options*! $\forall$-elimination lets you deduce $P(t)$ from $\forall xP(x)$ for *any* term $t$ in your language. E.g. suppose my language has a constant symbol $c$ and a unary function symbol $f$. Then these are some of the things I could deduce from $\forall xP(x)$:

- $P(y)$ (here $y$ is a variable - and it's *free* in the formula $P(y)$).
- $P(c)$ (here $c$ is my constant symbol - there are no variables at all occurring in $P(c)$).
- $P(f(c))$ (still no variables).
- $P(f(y))$ (now I have a free variable $y$ in my formula, *but* the term I've selected is $f(y)$, which is more than *just* a free variable).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept this one. Better late than never I hope, sorry again!